# UISplitViewController extension makes trouble for the app

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a simple extension for `UISplitViewController`:

```
extension UISplitViewController {

    var masterViewController: UIViewController? {
        return (viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController
    }
}
```

Within some `UIViewController` I did connect modal segue to my `UISplitViewController`. When segue is being performed then I prepare my `destinationViewController` like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let searchResultsViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as? UISplitViewController)?.masterViewController as? SearchResultsViewController {
        searchResultsViewController.mode = mode
    }
}
```

And it **DOESNT WORK** because of error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'The content view controller argument must be the root of its associated view controller hierarchy.'

However when I remove extension for `UISplitViewController` and prepare `destinationViewController` like this:

```
if let searchResultsViewController = ((segue.destinationViewController as? UISplitViewController)?.viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController as? SearchResultsViewController {
    //prepare controller
}
```

**IT WORKS**

> What is the reason that it is not working in first case?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the name of your computed variable from `masterViewController` to something else. It seems you are overriding an internal property of the `UISplitViewController`.

This works and is not called during the setup of the `UISplitViewController`.

```
var masterVC: UIViewController? {
    return (viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController
}
```

This is called by something in the SDK and causes a crash.

```
var masterViewController: UIViewController? {
    return (viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController
}
```

Comment: Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Please, note that I understand what to do to fix this problem. I need an EXPLANATION why should I do this.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk No this is not documented however you can see the property in question from the [private headers](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/1bdbef2afe228bd5e660e247cdb149e1b39a85c4/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UISplitViewController.h#L307)